# Deleting Photo Cache Ready to use URL Link

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a site that allows a person to register and become a member on my site. Members may upload their photos and profiles will be stored in the folder cPanel.

I use a small hosting, so it must strive to save space in various ways. Photo members will always have a URL based on their username. So if upload new photos, the old photos will be deleted.

For example, members have a name *jonathan* then url image will be `domain.com/photos/jonathan.png` though he changed his picture photo URL will remain the same as before.

I use a storage cache on `.htaccess` and this is the point of my question.

If users change the image, then the URL will remain, but the photos turned into a new one. However, new photos will not be seen because the cache has not been replaced. If I change the settings `.htaccess` in the same folder *photos* forcing everyone to reload the photo each time you open the page there is a picture.

I wish there was an easy way to clear this cache directly on the photo url link. For example, by opening the link `domain.com/photos/jonathan.png?cache=remove` and the like.

Could the way that I use?